# Refusal of Schengen visa by Spain’s embassy in Pakistan

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, pakistani-citizens

The embassy of Spain recently refused my tourist visa, saying:

> one or more of members states consider you a threat to public policy, internal security, public health under article 2(21) of regulation (EC)no399/2016 Schengen barcode or international relations of one or more member states

Similarly my Schengen visa was refused by Germany, Hungary and Italy within the last year.

I am a 62 year-old Medical Doctor and have previously traveled to the United States, Australia, Canada, Brazil, South Africa, Japan, Russia, Singapore, Hongkong, Turkey and many more countries, but never to Schengen countries.

I was misguided by my travel agent and didn’t appeal any of them before the Schengen visa refusal.

How should I appeal now to clear myself to visit Schengen countries?

Thanks.

Comment: If your life is otherwise unremarkable, perhaps they have mistaken you for someone on a watchlist? But The refusal notice does mention public heath so I wondered if you have publicly advocated any controversial medical views.

Comment: @user16259 "threat to public health" is poorly defined in the English version of the Schengen Borders Code, but it is clear that it is intended to apply to carriers of certain contagious diseases.  To exclude a doctor advocating controversial medical views, a country would have to use grounds of public policy or perhaps public security.

Comment: You can ask the Consulate to reveal which country considers you a "threat."

Answer (score 1):

This question already has [an excellent answer by Gayot Fow](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57579/schengen-visa-refusal-on-threat-to-public-policy-security-health) - but since you're in Pakistan, there is one extra thing to check before you proceed with appeal:

Since you mentioned you used a travel agent, the first thing is to check whether the refusal is genuine and coming from the Consulate/Embassy. Pakistan is one of those countries where some unscrupulous travel agents were ripping people off by pocketing your visa application money, and give you a homemade refusal letter without submitting the paperwork. If you haven't been called to the Embassy for biometrics, this might be likely the case.

If you had, then please see the answer above.