# Schengen visa refusal article 2 (19)

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, netherlands, schengen-visas

Recently I applied for a Schengen visa in Netherlands for business purpose but the visa was refused, due to the reason below:

> One or more member state(s) consider you to be a threat to public policy, internal security or public health as defined in Article 2 (19) of Regulation (EC) No 562/2006 (Schengen Borders Code) or the international relations of one or more of the Member States). One or more EU Member States have lodged an objection to your entry into the Schengen Area. To issue a Schengen visa in the face of this objection would be damaging to international relations.

I have a good travel history including China, Singapore and UAE and also I traveled to Italy twice (2014 and May 2017). I got another visa in July 2017 but due to some reason I wasn’t able to travel and I never got any refusal or any problem getting a visa.

During my travel I never overstayed or done anything that may affect my travel history.

Can anyone tell what could have gone wrong which resulted in my refusal?

[image: Visa Refusal]

Comment: I suspect that the most likely thing to have "gone wrong" is that someone else with your name (or perhaps just using your name as an alias) has come to the attention of law enforcement authorities as a suspected criminal.  You will be most likely to overcome this if you can hire a good lawyer.  This ground of refusal is very serious -- it is the only ground under which an EU citizen can be denied entry to other EU countries -- so there is no chance whatsoever that it relates to overstays or similar issues with travel history.

Comment: @phoog i have asked the inviting company to Contact office mentioned in Final Verdict, now waiting for their reply

Comment: You may want to review the related questions in the side bar, especially [Schengen visa refusal on threat to public policy, security, health](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/57579/19400).

Comment: It is as phoog says, most likely the case of an identity mismatch. These do unfortunately happen. Your question is unfortunately also a duplicate of the question he is linking to. Please be aware that the only and heavily upvoted answer to that question is full of factual errors. Your first step should be to get information from the Dutch authorities on which Schengen state(s) objected to your visa application and then you will have to proceed from there with the relevant national authorities in each state.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo they haven’t mentioned the states who have raised the objections

Comment: I would be surprised if they ever mention which states have raised objections.

Comment: @phoog it would have been much easier than  anyway looking forward to reply from the company and will plan next step accordingly

Comment: Schengen consulates usually don't tell which country has objected if they use this reason of refusal. I am not sure though if the inviting company will have any luck solving this issue, unless you authorize them to appeal the decision for you. If you need a representative, depending on national regulations, the representative may have to be an authorized lawyer.