# Schengen Germany visa rejected

Tags: schengen, germany, visa-rejections

I applied for the Schengen visa and it got rejected citing the reason:

> One or more Member States consider that you pose a threat to the public order, internal security, public health Article 2 (21) of Regulation (EC) No 2016/399 (the Schengen Borders Code) or the international relations of one or more Member States.

1) I got the last Schengen visa from France and instead of entering France I made the first entry to Holland and came back from Holland itself. As my name is Abdullah, and I have seen in other articles that this name has some issues.

2) I had a visa issued by the German embassy in my old passport, which wasn't attached to my application as I only supplied the new passport.

Kindly guide me what should I do? I have one month to apply again. Shall I apply again and attach the old passport? Shall I provide clarification saying: I confess my mistake of having French visa and travelling to Holland?

[image: [enter image description here]]

Comment: Entering and exiting through the Netherlands with a French visa should not by itself cause anyone to think that you are a threat to public order, security, or health.  It's not even against the rules (although it could lead an officer to suspect visa fraud or other violations).  So making a statement about your "mistake" (which may not even be a mistake) will certainly not help anything.

Comment: thank you,so simply i apply again asking them to seeing again my application ?

Comment: No. Follow the advice given by Gayet Fow in the SE.Travel question linked above by Henning Makholm.

Comment: @David is correct.  They've probably linked you to some serious criminal activity.  A new application will not cause them to reconsider whether that link is justified or whether the activity is as dangerous as they believe.  Your only viable option is to challenge their finding through some other means, for which a lawyer is almost certainly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that was given means that at least one Schengen country considers **you, personally,** to be a threat. That's much more specific than "justification for the purpose and conditions ... was not reliable" or "intention to leave ... could not be ascertained." They believe that **you** match a person in a terrorist threat database or the like (e.g. a criminal database).

- It could be a mistaken identity. They think that there is a terrorist named Abdullah and they falsely believe that you are this person.
- It could be a misinterpreted action. You did something and they falsely believe that it ties you to a terrorist context.

Either way, a new application will not help until this is cleared up. As phoog mentioned in his comment, read the [linked answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57579/schengen-visa-refusal-on-threat-to-public-policy-security-health) by Henning and get a lawyer.

Comment: It's not necessarily terrorism, of course; it could be other criminal activity. There are also some other possibilities, such as that the applicant really is involved in something shady but the determination that it rises to the level of a threat to public safety is contrary to law.  In this case that seems unlikely since there is a history of visas having been issued.

Comment: @phoog, I added that example.

Comment: thank you everyone, i live in dubai, so the lawyer should be from germany or any specific qualified lawyer ? any idea how much they charge ? ( any rough idea ?) thank you ance again

Comment: @abdULLAH I suppose I would start with a German lawyer, who may be able to help you find out more details about the refusal.  The next step would depend on the circumstances. If Germany connected you unjustly to a real database entry, then the remedy probably lies in German law.  If Germany connected you correctly to an unjust entry in a database, then you probably need a lawyer in whichever country it was that created that entry.

Comment: isn't complicated to know from which country i got banned ?!

Comment: i have never deal with any lawyer, so what kind of lawyer can do my job ? what should be his designation? in what he should professional?

Comment: @abdULLAH: **Ausländerrecht** ("foreign people law")

Comment: I like to add, if you don't know what the offense might be, you may have acted as a transfer agent for Hawala or another inofficial money transfer system in the past. That's often used for tax evasion and terror financing and may gave you that "criminal activities" tag.

Comment: @abdULLAH: German lawyers charge fixed fees based on the "amount of dispute". The lawyer calls that amount before he starts working on your case (10000-15000€ seems reasonable), and his fee is roughly 20% of that amount. You have to pay it in advance. In addition, there are also court fees, a few hundred Euro per stage.

Comment: thank you everyone, i will update here how it goes.. wish me good luck 

Comment: @abdULLAH any updates?