# My wife applied for a schengen visa through Russia and was rejected on basis of falsifying documents

Tags: schengen, russian-citizens, visa-rejections

My wife paid a travel agency to help her get a schengen visa. She was surprisingly rejected considering we have been to dozens of trips to Europe together.
The rejection letter was alarming and we don't know what to make of it. The travel agency has no answers. Hotel and airline tickets are in my hand and valid. Nothing about the application looks in error. 
However...

The rejection letter states:

"The Moscow diplomatic mission checked your visa application. The visa application is rejected. This decision is based on the following reason (s): The purpose and conditions of the intended stay have not been established. 2. One or more Member States believe that they pose a threat to public order, internal security, public health in accordance with Article 2 No. 21 of Regulation (EC) No. 2016/399 (Schengen Borders Code) or international relations one or more Member States. The information provided about the purpose and conditions of the intended stay was not credible.

The hotel / flight booking you submitted has since been canceled.
You tried to fool the embassy by submitting false or falsified documents or by providing contradicting or incorrect information in the visa process. You have been informed against a signature in the visa application that incorrect information or the submission of falsified documents can lead to the rejection of your application. Your purpose of stay was not apparent from the submitted documents, 3 You have provided contradictory information about the purpose of your stay."

How screwed is my wife in trying to re-apply? There is no clarification on why she is considered a security threat. Never had any trouble with past visas or visits to any schengen countries...
Has anyone experienced any of this??

Comment: Did you see the application and documents that the agency submitted on her behalf? Are you sure they even submitted it?

Comment: It is important to look into this. If it is real an allegation of false documents could have long term consequences.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57579/schengen-visa-refusal-on-threat-to-public-policy-security-health

Comment: Get a lawyer immediately. The Internet can't help you with this.

Comment: Do you have any idea why the embassy would say "You tried to fool the embassy by submitting false or falsified documents or by providing contradicting or incorrect information"?

Comment: Embassies do not cancel bookings (at least not in Schengen countries). This looks rather like a fake letter. Schengen rejections are standard form. You can compare the letter to that. You can also check the status of the application yourself.

Comment: It is hard to conceive that an embassy/consulate employee would ever use the word "fool" in a Schengen visa rejection letter...

Comment: There may be a translation issue. What language was the letter in?

Comment: @DJClayworth while I agree that the letter looks suspicious, I’m pretty sure it isn’t claiming that the booking was cancelled *by the embassy*.

Comment: @ChrisH I agree. That is probably the cause of the false/falsified documents. The question is who cancelled the flight after the application? Travel agent or OP?

Comment: Good point. I agree. Should be easy for the OP to check the status of the bookings. It's also possible the booking was automatically cancelled, either for non-payment or because it was done through a site that just provides bookings for visa purposes.

Comment: Can you indeed clarify what language the letter was in? Some of the language does not look like officialese :-)

Comment: Could you scan or take take a photo of the rejection letter (with personal data removed)? The embassy should have used a standard form, with references to national law and instructions on how to appeal. Until I have seen the letter, my guess is that it is not from any embassy, but from a scammer.

Comment: To the commenters: Maybe they found the ticked were cancelled (or fake) so they think she submitted false documents. Being (probably) a translation doesn't help understanding better.  Note: it is not a good sign that agency will not answer you. About security treat: between Russia and few European countries... there is lack of trust (you see with much long questionnaire). Wrong information could give hints about spying. [But there is also political play between some countries, so you may be just a pawn.

Comment: Please post an image of the original rejection letter with identifying information blacked out.

Comment: Have you checked if the flight tickets and hotel reservations have remained valid from the time before your application until after it was rejected?  Perhaps there was an honest mistake and sometime was cancelled, or perhaps the travel agency tried to cheat you (one common scam: you pay them cash, they use a stolen credit card to buy flights which they submit to you and the embassy, when/if the stolen card is reported the flights get canceled).