# Does a Schengen visa refusal affect negatively Australian PR visa approval?

Tags: visa-refusals, schengen-visas, australia, italy, iraqi-citizens

I am Iraqi passport holder living currently in Iraq with no valid Australian visa. I received an invitation to lodge my 189 visa and I am in process of lodging my PR visa. 
While I was studying in Australia 2012-August 2017 (completed and returned back to Iraq), I had a Schengen Visa refusal in March 2017 to Italy as I was going for a conference.

I did something wrong during the Italian visa process. The thing I did was I withdrew my passport from the Italian embassy (between the time of lodging my visa application to the refusal date). I withdrew passport because I had to travel to USA for another conference and the embassy did not issue visa as quick as usual. While I was in USA, I received an email by Italian embassy stating:
"One or more member state(s) consider you to be a threat to public policy, internal security, public health as defined in Article 2(19) of Regulation (EG) No 562/2006 (Schengen Borders Code) or the international relations of one or more of the member of states".
Within this received email, they give me a chance to explain everything. I did and said that I withdrew my passport for this reason with a lot of supportive documents.

After returning to Australia, I sent back my passport and they sent me this refusal with the same reason quoted above. I am very confident that I do no have anything to hide.

I checked this https://accra.diplo.de/blob/1120620/1c3be7eadcc793be49d586d77787604c/schengen-visa-refusal-data.pdf. I want to local German consulate and sought AZR. I received that "no details are stored under your name". So, the only possibilities, they considered when making decision for my schengen visa, are deceit or false/fake/contradictory.

Q1: How is to mention the above refusal reason in "circumstances of refusal" this form https://immi.homeaffairs.gov.au/form-listing/forms/80.pdf?

Q2: How severe is this refusal on the likelihood of getting my Australian PR visa approved?

Q3: What is the best approach to handle this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need to consult an Immigration lawyer. Does this answer your question? [Schengen visa refusal on threat to public policy, security, health](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57579/schengen-visa-refusal-on-threat-to-public-policy-security-health)

Comment: No, it does not answer my questions. I am applying for Australian visa and had two different visas with two different countries including (USA) issued under my name. Should I solve Schengen refusal and then apply for Australian visa? or just apply for Australian and mentioned this refusal?

Comment: Why did you approach the German embassy instead of the Italian embassy? Why don't you ask the Italians why exactly they consider you a threat?

Comment: AZR is the database of EU members based in Germany. How am I supposed to ask Italians? I do not know but maybe because of the wrong thing that I did. Read my post again.

Comment: Yes, but what does Germany have to do with the situation? It's Italy who made the decision, and only Italy knows why. Not being in a German database has absolutely nothing to do with that.

Comment: @user109341 The suggested duplicate states categorically that to clear up such a refusal you need the assistance of a lawyer, not random strangers on the internet. It also states that such a refusal isn’t made for trivial reasons, such as withdrawing your passport mid-application to Italy. An Immigration lawyer will have the expertise to advise you on what you need to do to address the refusal and the timing of your Australian application. I don’t see why you went to the German Consulate for help rather than the Italian Consulate, since it was Italy that issued the refusal.

Comment: Dear @Traveller, I went to German consulate in order to get AZR. Only German authorities can disclose AZR to the world. Other states do not accept to share this information. It proofs that my name is not listed as a person who should not come to EU. It means that Italian embassy considered my case as fake or false or contradictory. I asked the Italian embassy for more details, but no answer received. The question is why would I have to satisfy a country with my honesty through lawyers and court before I going to apply to another (totally different) country?

Comment: @user109341 You asked the opinion of TSE members and we’ve given it. You need to clear the refusal reason before applying to Australia because you’ll have to declare the refusal and the reason in your application and when the Australian authorities see that they will reach out to the Italian authorities to find out more. Or just refuse you the visa outright. But you’re free to go ahead and apply to Australia irrespective of that advice, as Tootea said in their answer.

Comment: @Traveller, thanks for your advice, I wish the Australian authorities to contact Italian authorities to find out more as I have nothing to hide for both sides. The only reason could be related to the bad reputation of Iraqi passport. I would go for lawyers and court if I had done something trouble in schengen zone. Since I am not, I will apply and mention everything honestly and see how it goes.

Answer (score 3):

A [refusal for being a security threat](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/57579/schengen-visa-refusal-on-threat-to-public-policy-security-health) is a **Bad Thing**™. You'll have to **enlist the help of a competent lawyer** specializing in these matters if you ever want to enter the Schengen area again. See the linked question for more details on this.

Now, in theory, Australia is free to make its own determination as to whether you're a risk or not, so you could still be granted the visa anyway.

However, you absolutely have to mention this refusal on your Australian application, and provide a complete and bullet-proof explanation of why exactly Schengen doesn't want you in. I personally don't see anything close to such a credible explanation in your question, but then I'm not an Australian visa officer.

Thus although there's nothing stopping you from applying anyway, I'd consider the risk of a refusal to be pretty high. I suspect you'll have to sort out the Schengen issue first.