# How can I find my data in the Schengen information system?

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, overstaying, ethiopian-citizens

I overstayed by 12 days in Sweden. The last time I applied for a short-term Schengen visa it was denied because of the overstay. How can I find my personal data in the Schengen information system about my penalty?

Comment: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/67358/1362 may be relevant.

Comment: Note that even if there is no "ban" in the system, any new visa decision will take your history into account.

Comment: You can submit an access request to Sweden (if they were the ones who recorded your overstay).  Also, which member state gave you a refusal?

Answer (score 3):

As was noted by @GayotFow, you can make an Subject Access Request to Sweden and/or to the country which refused your visa application (should it be other than Sweden).

[The Schengen Information System Guide for Exercising the Right of Access](https://www.datainspektionen.se/Documents/diverse/dok-schengen-handbok-eng.pdf) provides the contact details for Sweden, at page 62 (as well as the other Member States):

> Requests for access must be made to the National Police Board (Rikspolisstyrelsen), which is the authority responsible for the Swedish unit of the Schengen Information System.
>
> Rikspolisstyrelsen
>   Box 12256
>   Polhemsgatan 30
>   S - 102 26 Stockholm
>   Tel.: ++46 (0)8-401 90 00
>   Fax: ++46 (0)8-401 99 90
>   E-mail: rikspolisstyrelsen@polisen.se
>   Internet: www.polisen.se
>
> Requests must be made in writing to the National Police Board and signed personally by the applicant. In general, a request for access must be answered within one month. Applicants are entitled to free access to information once every calendar year.